# Run a Vue.js project in server without " npm run dev " command?

Tags: vuejs2

After installing vue cli globally by running `npm install -g vue-cli`, I have installed all the modules in the project folder "myBlog" by running `npm install` and can run the project in my local environment by using `npm run dev`. But when I am going to move this project in the live server is this is the right way to run the batch program (`npm run dev`) continuously or there are other ways to run the project without running `npm run dev` continuously?

Answer (score 7):

It's not Vue specific but you also should be able to run `npm run build` which generates production bundles in `/dist` subfolder of your project. You are supposed to copy this folder to the production server and configure the server so that it serves `dist/index.html` for every URL.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the "webpack", "webpack-simple" or "pwa" template there is a dedicated command for creating the production build, which allows a static hosting (with no need to run any npm process in the server):

`npm run build`

It will create a `dist` folder which content you can upload to the root of your server.

---

Some more info about:

- "webpack" template:
  https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/commands.html#npm-run-build
- "webpack-simple":
  https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple#webpack-simple
- "pwa": https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa#whats-included

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. To launch a VueJs project, you must type "npm run serve".

Comment: What's the benefit of `npm run serve` over `npm run build` suggested in the top-voted answer?

Comment: The answer to your question is in the package.json file.

Comment: Hmm. Can you expand on that? I’m not following. What am I looking for in the `package.json` file? I’m trying to make sure your answer is clear and useful to future readers.